# Countdown timer giving me negative numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have made a countdown timer in Python3. I have set the month to `1` and the day set to `10` just as examples. When I run it I get negative numbers because that date has already passed.

So then my question is how can I set the year to be something like `2017` so that instead of getting negative numbers I get something like `392` days.

**Countdown Timer**

```
import time
from datetime import datetime

while True:
    Datetime = datetime.now()
    Month = 1 - Datetime.month
    Day = 10 - Datetime.day
    Hour = 24 - Datetime.hour
    Minute = 60 - Datetime.minute
    Second = 60 - Datetime.second

    Month = str(Month) + " " + "Month"
    Day =  str(Day) + " " + "Day"
    Hour = str(Hour) + " " + "Hour"
    Minute = str(Minute) + " " + "Minute"
    Second = str(Second) + " " + "Second"

    print(Month)
    print(Day)
    print(Hour)
    print(Minute)
    print(Second)

    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I don't think you need the [python-2.7] tag since you're using python 3, as is evident by the print statements so i'm editing it out

Comment: @RegisteredUser Oops, sorry I did not mean to put that in there.

Comment: no problem. sincerely, Alex :D

Comment: [Take a look at this post on good examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  It is very helpful for you to give the *minimum* code required to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix I will work on that right now.

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix I just updated the code

Comment: @Alex nice update, much easier to parse!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to calculate by hand. Just use the capabilities of the `datetime` module. It offers time delta calculations:

```
import datetime
import time

target_date = datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 11)
timedelta_zero = datetime.timedelta(0)

while True:
    diff = target_date - datetime.datetime.now()
    if diff <= timedelta_zero:
        break
    print(diff)
    time.sleep(1)
print('Takeoff!!!')
```

prints:

```
393 days, 17:09:19.278093
393 days, 17:09:18.276930
393 days, 17:09:17.274710
393 days, 17:09:16.272841
393 days, 17:09:15.270777
393 days, 17:09:14.268744
393 days, 17:09:13.267112
```

If you don't like the microseconds, just strip them off:

```
>>> print(str(diff).rsplit('.')[0])
393 days, 17:09:19
```

You need `datetime.timedelta(0)` as zero value for your time delta comparison.
For testing, set `target_date` to a date just a few second in the future. There should be no negative dates.

Comment: Thanks for your help I really do appreciate it.

Comment: Could you please explain what `datetime.timedelta(0)` is doing in the code because it works fine if I take that all out.

Comment: @Alex Ups, this is a leftover from testing. Removed it from my answer.

Comment: @Alex `datetime.timedelta(0)` actually serves a purposes. I check against it to stop when the time delta gets negative.  See my updated answer.

Comment: Is there any other way to set the `target_date` without using `datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 11)`? Just out of curiosity mind you.